# CakePHP 3.x: set variable from ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, post, cakephp

The goal is to set a variable (stored into `AppController.php`) whenever the user select a new value from a list.

**`nav-top.ctp`**

```
<?= $this->Form->create(false, ['id' => 'ajaxForm']) ?>
<?= __('Year') ?>
<?= AppController::year(); ?>  <---- just for test
<select name="currentYear">
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021" selected>2021</option>
</select>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>

...

<?php $this->append('script'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#currentYear").on("change", function() {
        let ajaxdata = $('#ajaxForm').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "app/setYear",
            data: ajaxdata,
            success: function(data) {
                $(document.body).html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $(document.body).html(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

**`AppController.php`**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    private $_year = 2021;

    ...

    public function year()
    {
        return new Date($this->_year . '-01-01');
    }

    public function setYear()
    {
        $this->_year = $this->request->getData('currentYear');
        return $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

When I change the current item in the `select` the POST is correctly fired and I get the new value inside the `setYear()` method.

Then the page reloads, as expected. But all the queries that rely on the `year()` function, i.e.:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => [
            'Customers',
            'ProformaStates',
            'ItemProformas' => ['ItemDeliveryNotes' => ['DeliveryNotes']]
        ],
        'conditions' => [
          'proforma_date >=' => AppController::year()
        ],
        'order' => ['proforma_number' => 'desc']
    ];
    $proformas = $this->paginate($this->Proformas);
    $this->set(compact('proformas'));
}
```

still use the old value, like it has not changed.
Furthermore, if I enable the test line above (to printout in the reloaded page the actual value of `year`) I get the following error:

> Using $this when not in object context

Comment: Every page load is a completely new instance of everything. This is why your value is not persisting. What you are looking for is called "session" data, there's loads of documentation and examples and tutorials out there about it.

Comment: To be sure, you say the page reloads? That means it is a new request, and therefore your value is lost. Make sure to store in in your session or cookie, or send it along with a request if you need it in another request as well. Edit: just noticed Greg's answer, basically the same.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing it out! I thought the AppController would persist across reloadings! Yep, I know how to use sessions/cookies. I'm going to proceed in that way.

Comment: Your comments should be answers, though!